# Как исключить библиотеку из сборки Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, aar

Всем привет. Написал библиотеку на `Java в Android Studio`, использую в ней несколько библиотек импортированных в зависимости в качестве `jar` архива. При билде нужно исключать один из них при сборке в aar архив. Если открыть сбилденный aar архив, в папке libs будет архив `classes.jar` который нужно исключать, мне приходится каждый раз его удалять руками из билда, как это можно автоматизировать на моменте билда?

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос оказывается очень легко решается, в `build.gradle` при импорте библиотеке в зависимости, ту библиотеку которую не нужно добавлять в итоговый билд нужно импортировать как `compileOnly` а не `implementation`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    compileOnly files('C:\\Assets\\Plugins\\Android\\classes.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```